# How to get sympy to print a decimal answer when using the solve function?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

When solving an equation, how can I print a decimal instead of a fraction?

```
a=2*12
l=38*12
x=l/2
E=29000000
i = sym.Symbol('i')
goal = l/360
string_ridge = (l**4)-(2*(l**2)*(x**2))+(l*(x**3))-(2*(a**2)*(l**2))+(2*(a**2)*(x**2))
deltax=((((Ridge_Beam_Load)*x)/(24*E*l*i))*(string_ridge))-goal
solve(deltax)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only have a single variable (and you have a good idea of the neighborhood of the answer) you could just use nsolve(f(x), x, x_guess) or, if the equation can be solved (as in this case), just evaluate the result:

```
>>> solve(deltax,i)
[17476371*Ridge_Beam_Load/906250]
>>> _[0].n()
19.2842714482759*Ridge_Beam_Load
```

Note: watch out for integer division when defining x; I used x = S(l)/2 where S() converts l to a SymPy Integer rather than a python int.